# Twitter bootstrap/Simple form causes weird sized text boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have the following form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @text_message, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :client %>
  <%= f.input :unit_type %>
  <%= f.input :message %>
  <%= f.input :call_type %>
  <%= f.input :lead_type %>
  <%= f.input :from_number %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                text_messages_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the standard scaffolding generated for a model's "EDIT" form by the gem `twitter-bootstrap-rails`.

All of the text boxes created are really small in height and length. How do I, using bootstrap, go about adjusting the size of each "`f.input`"? I am using rails 4.0.0 and the latest version of `twitter-bootstrap-rails`.

Comment: As I have not looked into this, my first assumption is to delete the scaffolds.css.scss that got created if you scaffolded a model.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing all instances of "`import @bootstrap`" from my .css files.